# How Can I Play A Video Using Python?

Tags: python, video

I wanna create a simple program that help me to open any video i want, just by writing the name of the video; Is there any libraries i can use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

the most common way to work with images and videos in python is using opencv, a powerfull library that allows you to read imgs, videos and show them. If you only want to reproduce a video you can use a code like this:

```
import cv2


videoName = yourVideoPathAndName #'DJI_0209.MP4'

#create a videoCapture Object (this allow to read frames one by one)
video = cv2.VideoCapture(videoName)
#check it's ok
if video.isOpened():
    print('Video Succefully opened')
else:
    print('Something went wrong check if the video name and path is correct')


#define a scale lvl for visualization
scaleLevel = 3 #it means reduce the size to 2**(scaleLevel-1)


windowName = 'Video Reproducer'
cv2.namedWindow(windowName )
#let's reproduce the video
while True:
    ret,frame = video.read() #read a single frame 
    if not ret: #this mean it could not read the frame 
         print("Could not read the frame")   
         cv2.destroyWindow(windowName)
         break

    reescaled_frame  = frame
    for i in range(scaleLevel-1):
        reescaled_frame = cv2.pyrDown(reescaled_frame)

    cv2.imshow(windowName, reescaled_frame )

    waitKey = (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF)
    if  waitKey == ord('q'): #if Q pressed you could do something else with other keypress
         print("closing video and exiting")
         cv2.destroyWindow(windowName)
         video.release()
         break
```